# Convert NetCDF(.nc) (TROPOMI Sentinel-5p) to GeoTIFF (GDAL, GRASS)

Tags: raster, gdal, grass-gis, netcdf, sentinel-5p

I tried converting NetCDF (Sentinel-5p) file to GeoTIFF file but I'm getting:

```
D:\>gdalinfo 20181119T121048.nc
Warning 1: Recode from UTF-8 to CP_ACP failed with the error: "Invalid argument".
Warning 1: 20181119T121048.nc is a netCDF file, but without any dimensions >= 2.
```

Comment: Where did you get the file from? Note some potentially related discussion in the gdal-dev mailing list on the CAMS netCDF files: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2018-November/049367.html and subsequent emails (bug fixed in the GDAL 2.3.3 and later, see https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/Release/2.3.3-News). However, maybe your issue is a different one.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, I need to convert selected bands of Sentinel 5p to geotiff and havent found an automated way. Are you still stuck or did you find a way?

Comment: ... does GDAL 2.3.3+ work for you?